# Animation content on UIScrollView memory allocation

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I make an animation on the content in the scroll view and I have a problem with memory. So I have UITabBarController and in the 3 tabs I have a custom UIView which have a UIScrollView. I use this to animate the horizontall content scrolling:

```
- (void)beginAnimation
{
if (isAnimating) {
    return;
}

[scrollView setContentOffset:[self startOffset]];

isAnimating = YES;

NSTimeInterval animationDuration = (scrollView.contentSize.width / self.tickerSpeed);

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointZero;

                     if (self.scrollingDirection == BBScrollingDirectionFromRightToLeft) {
                         finalPoint = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, 0);
                     } else if (self.scrollingDirection == BBScrollingDirectionFromLeftToRight) {
                         finalPoint = CGPointMake(-scrollView.contentSize.width + self.frame.size.width, 0);
                     }

                     scrollView.contentOffset = finalPoint;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         isAnimating = NO;

                         [self beginAnimation];
                 }];
}
```

When I start the app and be on the first tab then everything is ok, but when I switch to the another tab, then overall bytes in the instruments allocation starting to grow up fast, live bytes are practically the same.
Can someone explain me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are creating an infinite loop by

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         isAnimating = NO;

                         [self beginAnimation];
                 }];
```

Why are you recursively calling begin animation through completion block? That would be my guess for your memory issues, blocks are saved into memory like other obj-c objects and they occupy space.

EDIT:

I suggest you to modify your animation call to smt like this and check again if you have memory issues:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    //I added autoreverse option also bc it seems like a good fit for your purpose
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10.0]; //This a class method, set repeat count to a high value, use predefined constants (ie HUGE_VALF) if it works for you 
                     ...
                 }
];
```

Comment: So what should I do to animate my content all the time, like in some ticker view?

Comment: But it does not work if I switch to other tab, also then the animation stops and if I come back to the first tab it does not animate anymore.

Comment: So your answer helped me now to solve the problem. I used UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat to repeat the animation and remove [self beginAnimation]; from the completion block (it made memory to grow up) and moved starting the animation from the viewDidLoad to the viewWillAppear method. Thanks.